# Unset billing fields with condition in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove some required billing fields if the checkout page based on a certain page template.

Everything in the code below works fine if I remove the if condition, but with the condition even though the fields are unset it still throws the required field error on submission. I also tried a different condition such as checking for a $_GET variable but that didn't work either, it is an option though.

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if ( is_page_template( 'page-simple.php') ) {
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
        return $fields;
    } else {
        return $fields;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
```

I've already ruled out a plugin or theme conflict by changing to twentysixteen and disabling all unnecessary plugins. I'm running the latest version of Woocommerce as of post. I'm running the One Page Checkout plugin to give me separate checkout pages, but ruled it out as the issue since this doesn't work with the regular checkout either when a condition is present.

Please let me know if I'm missing some information that would be helpful in troubleshooting this.

Comment: this page-simple.php is your checkout page?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: i believe this page is not in the theme root  directory right?

Comment: No it is in the theme root, plus I tried it on the twentysixteen theme using the $_GET condition. Are you referring to the url not being in the root? If so then yes, the url is in the root also